# Rally: Is there an easy way to obtain all user stories under a portfolio item?

Tags: javascript, rally

I know that I might be able to recursively obtain the children of each portfolio item and then keeping querying the children of the previously obtained children.  However, I was wondering whether there is an easier solution to obtain all the user stories under a portfolio item.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to do this in an app? Or using a REST toolkit? Either way, I do not believe it is possible. Looking at some results, it looks like only the top parent User Story has a reference to the Portfolio Item it is associated with. Otherwise, the Portfolio Item is omitted from any children User Stories, with only a reference to the previous level's parent User Story. It seems that the only way to drill down, is to start by retrieving all the top level User Stories, and then recursively check for children and retrieve those.